# Add a grouping to a total in SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I have a matrix working the way I want it to. It shows the counts of appt type, the percentages of these appt types, and the totals for each provider by day. On the far right I am able to add a total column for the count of appointments regardless of type.  My last issue is being able to group the totals by appt type similar to how its being done grouped under daydate. How do i get the total to be grouped by appt type? Because it is a total and not a column group, I cant figure out how to add a grouping

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Îf you have a grouping hierarchy for example

```
1. Continent 'Group Name: GrpContinent
2. Country   'Group Name: GrpCountry
3. City      'Group Name: GrpCity
```

you can evaluate totals for each group level, when you add the scope in the aggreagate function.

```
'This two are the same. If you dont add the scope it takes the whole data from the dataset
=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value) 
=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "GrpContinent")

'Sum per Country
=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "GrpCountry")

'Sum per City
=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "GrpCity")
```